# problem with generating marginnote.sty from marginnote.dtx

Tags: marginnote, dtx

Running marginnote.dtx (latest version from CTAN) with pdflatex results in the following files:

```
marginnote.aux
marginnote.glo
marginnote.idx
marginnote.log
marginnote.pdf
marginnote.toc
```

That's all. No marginnote.sty or something like this!

What's wrong?

Comment: Try to run pdftex, not pdflatex.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. marginnote.sty has been produced. I am a bit surprised as far as I believe that "in former times" other dtx-files could have been processed with pdflatex, too. Is this a memory error?

Comment: Some .dtx  are quite clever and unpack with tex and create the docu with latex.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. You want to put this into an answer? I would like to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `pdflatex` on a dtx, this normally (as in your case) compiles the documentation.

To unpack the .sty and other files you normally have to run `pdflatex` or `pdftex` on an accompanying `.ins` file.

Some `.dtx` use some clever code and unpack if you run `pdftex` (or `tex`) on the `dtx` and create the documentation if they detect `pdflatex`.